# What is the proper way of reusing functions across different files within CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I have this function which I use in more than one model.

```
// Returns TRUE if the array of values supplied
// each correspond to a column in the database table.
// Else returns the value of the bad column.
private function _columns_exist( $columns, $table ) {

    foreach( $columns as $key => $value ) {

        if( !$this->db->field_exists( $key, $table ) ) {

            return $key;

        }

    }

    return TRUE;

}
```

What is considered the correct way to write the function once, and reuse it from many different files?

Do I want to create a whole library just for this one function?

Comment: Does this method have to remain `private`?

Comment: I don't imagine it has to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of CodeIgniter is that there are basically two types of custom functions. Ones that live in Libraries as library methods and ones that live in Helpers as simple functions.

The difference between them is minimal and it is for you to decide where to keep them, but the best practice is that helper functions are mostly standalone and library methods are the ones that use CI libraries like database, sessions, your other models.

For your function it's best to make a library and keep it there, but you can, as well, make a helper as you're not overusing any database querying. If it was me, I would make a helper:

Make a file in the `helpers` directory named `db_helper.php` and add an element `db` to helper array in `autoload.php` file. Note that you don't need to write the full name `db_helper`, only `db`.

Put this code in `db_helper.php` file you've created:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('_columns_exist')) {
    function _columns_exist( $columns, $table ) {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        foreach( $columns as $key => $value ) {
            if( !$CI->db->field_exists( $key, $table ) ) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this function anywhere - in your controllers, models, even view files as you would if it was a simple function:

```
_columns_exist($columns, $table)
```

Note that you don't use `$this` in helpers or libraries, you must get an instance of CodeIgniter singleton object first, then you manipulate it. You can find more info on this in the user guide or on StackOverflow.

Also see my comments to **darkdad**'s answer, that is another great approach I would go for.

Comment: +1 Both of you are right. But I really enjoyed of your approach.

Comment: While you are beginning to learn CI you can use mine, at some time you will find use-cases where dardad's is better

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a common function across models, you can extend the core model in the first place and get all your other models to extend that. Read more on extending core classes here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

```php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function common_func()
  {
    // content
  }
}
```

then you can use this function in all other models

```
class Some_model extends My_Model {

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function some_func()
  {
    // use the common function here
    $result = $this->common_func();
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that as the function in the question is not dependent on the object or data of this object it lives in, and thus you would get this method in any of the models in your project making some of them obsolete and repeated in general. I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm saying it's not the best way to do it

Comment: It would be a great solution if all the models would have a `table_name` property, then the function would only need one argument and the `$table` parameter variable could be changed to `$this->table_name` - that would be a great way to handle this functionality!

Comment: Well, the function OP mentioned seems to be something that would only be called within models. If you are checking columns outside of models, then that's a design issue. This is the problem with CodeIgniter (and why I'm moving to Lithium). With CodeIgnter, you can do anything anywhere - whether you use models, helpers or controllers is really up to you. I used to love this flexibility in CI during the early days, but now I know better. The framework should be guiding the user on which bit of code goes where. Just my opinion, not arguing the solution.

Comment: Sure, everyone's got their own point of view. About the design issue, this function should not be in any model as it has a table argument, thus, making it the helper function, the database helper function, to be precise, it all depends on how to look at the situation, anyway, I can't agree with your point on flexibility, the language or framework should not be responsible on how their users use them and the flexibility is sometimes needed for situations that can't be solved in normal ways :)